Proving that if $x \notin D$ then $x \in B$, given that $A \setminus B\subseteq C \cap D$ and $x \in A$
I'm reading Daniel Velleman's How to Prove It and I've set out to prove the following statement that appears on p. 94:

Suppose $A \setminus B\subseteq C \cap D$ and $x \in A$. Prove that if
$x \notin D$ then $x \in B$.

My attempt at the proof
We have $$\forall x(x \in A \land x \notin B) \implies (x \in C \land x \in D).$$ We are given that $x \notin D$, hence it follows that $x \notin C \cap D$ either, i.e. $x \notin \{x: x \in C \land x \in D\}$. Hence by modus tollens we have $x \notin \{x: x \in A \land x \notin B\}$. Hence one of the following three cases holds:

$x \notin A \land x \in B$;
$x \in A \land x \in B$;
$x \notin A \land x \notin B$.

But we are given that $x \in A$. Hence we have that $x \in A \land x \in B$, which implies $x \in B$, as required. $\square$
Can someone tell me (i) if this proof is correct, and (ii) if there is a way to make it cleaner and more compact?

Another possibility is to prove the contrapositive: assume $x \notin B$ and prove $x \in D$.

If $x\notin D$, then $x\notin C \cap D$, and by the inclusion $A\setminus B\subset C\cap D$, we get $x\notin A\setminus B = A \cap B^c$. Hence, $x\in (A\cap B^c)^c = A^c\cup B$. It is given that $x\in A$, so $x\notin A^c$. The only possibility is $x\in B$. $\,\textbf{q.e.d.}$

Thank you, I think this is what I was looking for: a more concise version of the proof in set-theoretic language. The proof I've written above is correct though, albeit long-winded?

@RiccardoIorio That's right, your proof is correct too!

Great. Thank you!
